# Migration to AWS - Https redirection issues (Drupal)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, drupal

I've setup SSL certification on AWS.

However, this seems to be automatically redirecting to https rather than hitting our vhosts file..

The pages are erroring out with the following...

```
mixed Content: The page at 'https://preprod-example.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://preprod-example.co.uk/modules/system/system.base.css?ow428z'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

The vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example/production"
    ServerName preprod-example.co.uk

    <Directory /var/www/html/example/production>
           order allow,deny
           allow from all
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example/production"
    ServerName preprod-example.co.uk

    <Directory /var/www/html/example/production>
           order allow,deny
           allow from all
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Where am I going wrong or is this maybe an issue with AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on

you can use SetEnvif just before your 443 virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example/production"
    ServerName preprod-example.co.uk

    <Directory /var/www/html/example/production>
           order allow,deny
           allow from all
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example/production"
    ServerName preprod-example.co.uk

    <Directory /var/www/html/example/production>
           order allow,deny
           allow from all
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Unfortunately CAPTCHA no longer function now... 
  https://preprod.example.com k/image_captcha?sid=122345&amp;ts=12121211212 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: check your server log  and let me know the real problem  i think error log has some answer for it